# Is /etc/paths built every time user logins from $PATH?

Tags: linux, macos, path, terminal

I am following a step by step guide to run an app on Mac from terminal. I noticed in the tutorial it adds values to $PATH in .profile, and then expects those values to appear in /etc/paths. So is /etc/paths dynamically created from $PATH at each login, or what is the relationship between the two?

In my case (Mac terminal) I can't see the values added to $PATH in /etc/paths after opening a new terminal. Not sure if I am doing something wrong. I am modifying $PATH in my .bash_profile. Would that make any difference?

Comment: I'd be most upset if something an ordinary mortal (non-root, non-administrator) user does while logging in goes and edits a configuration file like `/etc/paths`.  It would be most profoundly un-Unix-like.

Answer (score 1):

According to one of the answers in

- *[How to use /etc/paths.d to add executable files to my path?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128897/how-to-use-etc-paths-d-to-add-executable-files-to-my-path)*, OSX uses a program called [`path_helper`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/path_helper.8.html) which reads `/etc/paths` and in another answer to
- [how to set global PATH on OS X?](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x), the contents of files in `/etc/paths.d` also are added to the path.

A quick check with [`path`](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:path) confirms that it works as described.

To answer the question:

- Modifying your `.bash_profile` does not affect the system default `$PATH`.
- the contents of `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/` are not generated (mine are a year old).